# Why there isn't any output from "analyze table"?

Tags: hive

I am using analyze command on table, but the results shows nothing except OK. This is why?
The table business contains some simple columns with primitive type.

```
hive> ANALYZE TABLE business COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS;
Query ID = cloudera_20220315214949_eb44f89e-0c4c-44d1-bf7e-7c15a9f6af61
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1647302088953_0004, Tracking URL = http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1647302088953_0004/
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1647302088953_0004
Hadoop job information for Stage-0: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2022-03-15 21:49:45,229 Stage-0 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2022-03-15 21:49:49,328 Stage-0 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1.43 sec
2022-03-15 21:49:53,424 Stage-0 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 2.31 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 2 seconds 310 msec
Ended Job = job_1647302088953_0004
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-0: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 2.31 sec   HDFS Read: 10383 HDFS Write: 53 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 2 seconds 310 msec
OK
Time taken: 14.166 seconds
hive>
```

Comment: What extra info you want to see ? This is hive saying "i gathered stats successfully".

Comment: Ok, seems I am vague about the background. From the Language Manual: For new created table, it computs statistics automatically. For existing tables, user can use ANALYZE command to gather statistics.  So what "existing tables"  refers to?
Why they are not computed automatically? Thanks.

Comment: settings like `hive.stats.autogather=true, hive.stats.column.autogather=true`   says to gather stats  automatically for any tables for DML. For a new table, stats will be auto gathered when you do a insert/overrwrite. Now, for an existing table, unless you do insert/overwrite, it doesnt update the stats.

Comment: Could me give an example that for an existing table, when the stats will change (without doing insert/overwrite)?

Comment: it doesnt gather stats when you do nothing. Its not required if there is no data change.